# challenge with mongoose find() with $and query operator

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am getting error while using $and within mongoose find() method. Please help.

The UI has a search input and multiple filter dropdowns(mat-select). Based on selected filters a **filter-string** is constructed in the component method which looks like an array of objects.
This filter-string can be empty - represented by this string: `[]` or it can have one or more key value pairs representing the filter-dropdowns
e.g. `[{dueMonth:'2022-04'}, {servStatus:'Complete'}]`. However, this is still a string. Not sure if that is the reason for the error.

This filter-string is passed with the Http Post call along with other parameters like search string, page Index, sort key etc. The http call is as follows. Here 'filter' corresponds to the search input string. filtObj is the filter-string mentioned above.

**Angular Service**

```
getServiceLog(filter: string, sortKey: string, sortOrder: string, pageIndex: number, pageSize: number, filtObj: any)
: Observable<{servicelogs: ServiceLog[], totalCount: number, servLogFilts: ServLogFilts }> {
    if (sortKey === '' || !sortKey) { sortKey = 'servNumber'};
    if (sortOrder === '' || !sortOrder) { sortOrder = 'desc'};
    return this.httpClient.post<{servicelogs: ServiceLog[], totalCount: number, servLogFilts: ServLogFilts}>
    (this.reqUrl, {
        filter: filter,
        sortKey:  sortKey,
        sortOrder: sortOrder,
        pageIndex: pageIndex.toString(),
        pageSize: pageSize.toString(),
        filtObj: filtObj
    });
}
```

On the server side, the controller method is as follows.

**Node Controller**

```
exports.getServiceLog =  (req, res, next) => {
  filter = req.body.filter;
  sortKey = req.body.sortKey;
  sortOrder = req.body.sortOrder;
  pageSize = +req.body.pageSize;
  pageIndex = +req.body.pageIndex;
  filtObj = req.body.filtObj;

  servLogService.getServiceLog(filter, sortKey, sortOrder, pageSize, pageIndex, filtObj)
    .then(servLogData => {
      res.status(200).json(servLogData);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).json({
        message: "Server Error in fetching Service Log data!"
      });
    });
};
```

**Node Service** I have mentioned the switch cases that give error.

```
async function getServiceLog(filter, sortKey, sortOrder, pageSize, pageIndex, filtObj){
  let fetchedDocs;
  let docQuery;
  let filtType = 'none';

                     // NOTE: filtObj === '[]' means no filter was selected.
  if(filter && filtObj === '[]') {
    filtType = 'filter'
  } else if(!filter && filtObj !== '[]') {
    filtType = 'filtObj'
  } else if(filter && filtObj !== '[]') {
    filtType = 'both'
  }

  console.log('filtType', filtType)
  console.log('filtObj', filtObj)
  switch(filtType) {
    case "none":                                // THIS WORKS
      docQuery = ServiceLog.find().collation({ locale: 'en'});
      break;

    case "filter":                                // THIS WORKS
      docQuery = ServiceLog.find({
        $or: [
          { compName: { $regex:  filter, $options: 'i' } },
          { servName: { $regex:  filter, $options: 'i' } },
        ],
        }).collation({ locale: 'en'});
      break;

    case "filtObj":                    // THIS GIVES ERROR /////////////////////
      docQuery = ServiceLog.find({
            $and: filtObj               // e.g. filtObj: [{dueMonth:'2022-04'}, {servStatus:'Complete'}]
        }).collation({ locale: 'en'});
      break;

    case "both":                            // THIS GIVES ERROR /////////////////////
      docQuery = ServiceLog.find({
        $and: [
          {
            $or: [
              { compName: { $regex:  filter, $options: 'i' } },
              { servName: { $regex:  filter, $options: 'i' } },
            ],
          },
          {
            $and: filtObj
          }
        ]
        }).collation({ locale: 'en'});
      break;
  }

  if(pageSize && pageIndex >= 0) {
    if(!sortKey) {
      docQuery.skip(pageSize * pageIndex).limit(pageSize);
    }else{
      if(sortOrder === 'desc') {
        sortOption = '-' + sortKey
      }else {
        sortOption = sortKey
      }
      docQuery.sort(sortOption).skip(pageSize * pageIndex).limit(pageSize);
    }
  }

  fetchedDocs = await docQuery;
  if(!fetchedDocs) fetchedDocs = [];

  totalCount = await ServiceLog.countDocuments();
  if(!totalCount) totalCount = 0;

  servLogFilts = await getServiceLogFilters();

  servLogData = {
    servicelogs: fetchedDocs,
    totalCount: totalCount,
    servLogFilts: servLogFilts
  }

  return servLogData;
}
```

----EDITED: Added error----

```
errorIntercept: HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error", url: "http://localhost:3000/api/log", ok: false, …}
error: 
  message: 
    kind: "Array"
    path: "$and"
    stringValue: ""[{FY:'2021-22'}, {dueMonth:'2022-03'}]""
    value: "[{FY:'2021-22'}, {dueMonth:'2022-03'}]"
    __proto__: Object
 __proto__: Object
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/api/log: 500 Internal Server Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 500
statusText: "Internal Server Error"
url: "http://localhost:3000/api/log"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

Comment: what is the error

Comment: Added the error in the post. How do I use the filter-string created in angular as a real array for the $and query operator in node find()?

Comment: I tried to convert the filtObj in Node service like this: ```filtObj = JSON.parse(filtObj)```
But I still get an error, a different error - [object Object] - the message part of the above error is empty now.